# capture packets send by an application android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to capture the packets sent by an application in android. I know that there are ways to achieve this in a rooted device like using tcpdump etc.
But  i want this functionality to work in a non rooted normal device. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is, and should be, impossible from a user level account without special software like [Ettercap](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=887412).  You will probably need root to install it, but it should operate in userland after initialization.